# Name Error subfunction within class

Tags: function, python-3.x

i have a class with a few functions. Some functions within the class are related in this way.

```
class class1():
    ... init etc...
    def function1(inputs):
    do something
    return(output1)


    def function2(inputs):
        returnvals = function1(some_inputs)
        do something else
        return(output2)
```

when i call function 2 from script it give error:
`NameError: name 'function1' is not defined`

I also tried:

```
class class1():
    ... init etc...
    def function1(inputs):
        do something
        return(output1)

    def function2(inputs):
        returnvals = class1.function1(some_inputs)
        do something else
        return(output2)
```

But even than i get the same error...
How do I fix this.

Comment: Did you mean to type `self.function1(...)`?

Comment: No I didn't mean that. But I tried it and that don't work either...

Comment: Please properly indent your code. It's impossible (at least for me) to tell what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke i have a (ugly?) temporary Fix...
What works till now
What the working method is for now:

```
class class1():
    ... init etc...
    def function1(inputs):
        do something
        return(output1)

    def function2(inputs):
        temp = class1(some inputs)
        returnval = temp.function1()
        do something else
        return(output2)
```

In my opinion it is a ugly solution so if somebody knows a better one!! comment please!!